# sonarqube 4.5 has misidentified a cpp module as c - how can I fix it

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I created a multi-module project with a single sonar-project.properties. Most of the project is in c but one module is c++. I left the sonar.language property blank and ran sonar-runner with analysis.

The project and modules were created in the database and everything looked OK but when I did a preview on the same code I had a large number of new issues on the c++ project.

On closer inspection I found that the module in sonarqube was all wrong - it consisted of only the header files (.h) and most of the issues were the use of C style comments. It seems that the module was identified as a C module so all the .cpp files were ignored. However, in the preview the language was identified correctly and issues were found in the .cpp files that were clearly not know to sonarqube.

I cannot find any place in the UI to change the language of a module nor can I figure out a way to force it after the fact in my sonar-project.profiles.
First, sonar.language is apparently deprecated, and second, using module.sonar.language=cpp caused an error:

Caused by: sonar.profile was set to 'DEFAULT_C' but didn't match any profile for any language. Please check your configuration.

DEFAULT_C is something that we use for projects generally but not the one I'm working on. I have different profiles set up for different languages via the UI, but if I cannot get the analysis to see the correct language it doesn't help me much.

Any one have any idea how I can force the language of a module after the fact?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. I considered just deleting this but if I had found an answer on stackoverflow it would have eased my pain a little.

Brute force works.
Just set the language and the profile you want for the moudle and ignore complaints about such things being deprecated. Chosing a language won't force the right profile even if you have set up an explicit profile for the language in the UI - so just state it in the sonar-project.properties file.
In my case:
module.sonar.language=cpp
module.sonar.profile=MY_CPP_PROFILE

Throw sonar-runner at that and it will beat the backend into shape.